# Can I access data COPY'ed into a Snowflake table on S3 directly?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I loaded data into a table from an external stage by using COPY command. I know Snowflake compresses, encrypts, and saves all data to its "Storage Layer" shared across multiple Virtual Warehouses. Can I access my table's data directly on S3 storage layer?

I do not consider Unloading option.

Answer (score 2):

The data is not stored in virtual warehouses, but in an underlying storage account.
You can not access the files used by Snowflake after the data have been ingested.

(You can upload the files using PUT with SnowSQL to an internal snowflake stage, and then download the files using GET)